# Python: Getting Memory Error for large CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the following code snippet and I get the memory error on the last line `rows = list(reader)`

```
for file in fileList:
fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(file)
if fileExtension == ".csv":
    with open(path + '\\' + file, "rU") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', dialect="excel")
        rows = list(reader)
```

Is there any other approach I can use?

Comment: How large we talking?

Comment: Yes. Don't create a giant list out of your csv file. Just iterate over the `reader` and it will lazily produce each line.

Comment: @SuperStew Just under 2 Gb

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried running a for loop on the readerto process every row and even that didn't help.

Comment: @AdarshRavi i would suggest dumping it in a sqlite db and then just querying whatever you need so you don't have to load the whole thing in at once

Comment: What are you trying to do with each row you read? Do you actually need all the rows at once? If not, you should process each row one by one and discard the ones you've processed. Please update your question with your actual code if you're still in doubt.

Comment: @AdarshRavi then you are doing it incorrectly. Are you keeping the processed rows around?

Comment: @SuperStew  So the CSV file isn't properly formatted so I am trying to format the issue and create a new file or update the existing file, so I need to process all the rows or if there is a way I can create separate files even that is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've now stated in the comments that you simply want to fix the formatting of the rows, you definitely don't need all the rows at once. You should iterate through the csv reader one row at a time, fix the formatting of the row, write the row to another csv file, and then move on to the next row:

```
with open(path + '\\' + file, "rU") as f, open(path + '\\' + file + '.fixed', "w") as o:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', dialect="excel")
    writer = csv.writer(o, dialect='excel')
    for row in reader:
        # fix the formatting of the row here
        writer.writerow(row)
```